# Can't add password for user?

Tags: password

I have created a user account on a Linux server, now I want to create password
When I type passwd user1, it says:

```
 -- ERROR --
 The user user1 is currently authenticated from a remote source.
 Please change the password at the remote authentication server.
```

Does anyone know what is causing this?  Thanks

Comment: A remote auth source that isn't supported by PAM for password changes.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain more in details?

Comment: @Headandtoes Like RADIUS, TACACS, Kerberors, Active Directory etc.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that user1 is not authenticated via a password **on the local machine** (which would allow you, as an administrator of the local machine, to change their password) but it is authenticated via a **remote service** such as RADIUS, TACACS, Kerberos, AD, Diameter, etc. (See for instance [the AAA article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAA_(computer_security)).)

Therefore, you need to be an administrator of the remote auth service which is used to authenticate user1, and then change user1's password from there.